# How to fetch the result with proper query, wants to get isolated records?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I am using `Core Data` and `UITableViewController`. I have a table `category` with columns `name`, `descript` and `is_active` (boolean).

I want to fetch results like

```
SELECT * 
FROM CATEGORY 
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1
```

I have made this active through a form.

I am trying this code - in view I have this load section

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    IMSAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *category = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:context];
      NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    [request setEntity:category];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *srotDesc = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort, nil];

    [request setSortDescriptors:srotDesc];

    NSError *error;
     NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (results == nil) {
        //error handle here
    }

    [self setArr:results];
    NSLog(@"there is category array");

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [arr count];

    }
```

And In tableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Category *category = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [category name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [category descript];

    return cell;
}
```

It is showing all the records to me like all the name and the description.

I want to show those records only where is_active = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a predicate to your NSFetchRequest

```
...
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:category];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"is_active == 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
...
```

Comment: this scenario will be valid for other queries as-well?

Comment: Yes of course. And i suggest you to learn nsfetchedresultscontroller SDK object to manipulate CoreData and UItableView. You'll have simpler code

Comment: StackOverflow is full of good developper. Do not hesitate to post question. If there are attractive you will many answers.

Comment: actually i am making an app like inventory system and i need guidance in almost every turn.

Now there is a case like i have to use a `uipickerview` and am got stuck on that....

Comment: i was asking that for reason like if i have an question i will send you a message as well or inbox a link nothing else man :)

Comment: An UIPickerView uses the same datasource pattern that an UITableView

Comment: ok i will watch that out and post the link here as well if some error arise

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38058/discussion-between-ios-learner-and-tdelepine)